Show that the given stereographic projection is $\sigma(x)=u$

Let $N$ be the North pole $U_N=(0,\dots, 0, 1)$ and the South pole
$U_S=(0,\dots, 0, -1)$, where both are $\in \mathbb{S}^n\subseteq
 \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Define the stereographic projection
$\sigma:\mathbb{S}^n\backslash \{N\}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$\sigma(x^1,\dots,x^{n+1})=\frac{(x^1,\dots,x^n)}{1-x^{n+1}}$$ Let
$\tilde{\sigma}(x)=-\sigma(-x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{S}^n \backslash
 \{\mathbb{S}\}$.
For any $x\in \mathbb{S}^n\backslash \{N\}$ show that $\sigma(x)=u$,
where $(u,0)$ is the point where the line through $N$ and $x$
intersects the linear subspace where $x^{n+1}=0$.

I can use the local map  in the Euclidean space  for spheres, $\phi^{\pm}_i:U_i^{\pm}\cap \mathbb{S}^n \to\mathbb{B}^n$ given by:
$$\phi^{\pm}_i(x^1,\dots,x^{n+1})=(x^1,\dots,\hat{x}^i, \dots, x^{n+1})$$
then I would get
$$\phi^{-1}(\sigma) (U_N)=\sigma(0,\dots,0,\dots,0,1)=\frac{(0,\dots,0,1)}{1-0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$ (and that $U_N=-\tilde{\sigma}(U_S)$).
But how is $\sigma(x)=u$, when $\sigma(x)=\sigma(x^1,\dots x^n)$ ?
All I can refer to by the example of spheres (p. 5 Lee's Manifolds) is $f(u)=\sqrt{1-|u|^2}$, but I am not sure how to use this with $u$'s when the formula for the projections is in $x$'s
UPDATE:
With the given hint, I find that. Since $N=(0,\dots, 1)$ one obtains:
\begin{equation}
p(t)=(1-t)N+t(x^1,\dots x^{n+1})=\begin{cases}
(1-t)N=(0,\dots, 1-t)\\
t(x^1,\dots x^{n+1})=(tx^1,\dots tx^{n+1})
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
which totals to
$p(t)=(0,\dots, 1-t) + (tx^1,\dots, tx^{n+1})$
so we obtain the equation
$$tx^{n+1}+1-t=0$$
$$t(x^{n+1}-1)=-1\implies t=\frac{1}{1-x^{n+1}}$$

Hint: parametrize the line through $N$ and $(x^1,\ldots,x^{n+1})\in \mathbb{S}^n$ as $p(t) = (1-t)N + t(x^1,\ldots,x^{n+1})$, and determine for what value of $t \in \mathbb{R}$ does $p(t)$ belong to the equatorial plane ${x^{n+1}=0}$.

@Didier thanks for the tip. I think I don't understand still how to get to $\sigma(x)=u$. Do I need to find a formula which has u in it, related to sphere manifolds, except the one given, to solve the problem?

Just find the unique $t_0$ solving the hint stated above. Then look at $p(t_0)$: it is a vector of the form $(u,0) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R$, with $u \in \Bbb R^n$. You'll have a concrete expression for $u$ that will match the one given in your question

This is an equation type I have never seen. I assume the only value is for $t=1$

No it is not true. For $t=0$, $p(0) = N = (0,\ldots,0,1)$ which does not belong to the equatorial plane. This equation is very easy: it is a first order linear equation in $t$. Write the coordinates of $p(t)$ and find $t$ such that the last coordinate vanishes!

Do you mean $t$ must be in vector form to satisfy the problem, and be like $t=(t^1, t^2, \dots, t^{n+1})=\sigma(t)$?

No, $t$ is a scalar parametrizing the line through $N$ and $(x^1,\ldots,x^{n+1})$. Since $N = (0,\ldots,0,1)$, one has $p(t) = (tx^1,\ldots,tx^n,(1-t) + tx^{n+1})$. Hence the unique $t_0$ you are looking for satisfies $(1-t_0) + t_0x^{n+1} = 0$, and thus $p(t_0) = ...$

Thanks Didier. I made an update, I think I know what you meant

Didier, is $u$=t in the exercise context? Thanks

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
